# Exception Guard Idiom in Boost::Math::Quaternion

Tags: c++, boost, idioms

The implementation of `boost::math::quaternion` (you can browse it [here](http://boost.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost/boost/boost/math/quaternion.hpp?revision=1.15&view=markup)) uses an idiom commented as `// exception guard` extensively. For example:

```
template<typename X>
quaternion<T> &        operator += (quaternion<X> const & rhs)
{
    T    at = a + static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_1());    // exception guard
    T    bt = b + static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_2());    // exception guard
    T    ct = c + static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_3());    // exception guard
    T    dt = d + static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_4());    // exception guard

    a = at;
    b = bt;
    c = ct;
    d = dt;

    return(*this);
}
```

What is it meant by `// exception guard` in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading this code, you should say to yourself "why on earth make all these crazy temporaries, instead of just doing

```
a += static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_1());
b += static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_2());
c += static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_3());
d += static_cast<T>(rhs.R_component_4());
```

and be done with it?"

The comments are to answer your question: the temporaries are there so that if any of the operations throw an exception, the quaternion isn't partially modified. IE, the addition-assignment  should be atomic.

Comment: Finally! An answer that makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is all about [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) conversion, which tells the compiler to perform several type-conversion checks at compile-time, thus "guarding" your program from throwing an exception at run-time due to *quaternion* template class misuse.